# Java: Why does matrixes accept lines greater than the predefined length?

Tags: java, matrix, vector, variable-length

For instance:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][1];
int[] vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
matrix[0] = vector;
```

It compiles and runs normally, even though `vector` has a greater length than a line of `matrix` would stand for.

Why does Java accept this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][1];
```

Defines an array of `int` arrays. Specifically, it defines an array of size `3`. Each of those three elements is then initialized with a reference to a new array of size one, where that element is initialized with the value 0.

When you then do

```
matrix[0] = vector;
```

You are assigning a copy of the reference value stored in `vector` (which references an `int[]` with 5 elements) to the element at index 0 in `matrix`.

Because drawings are fun:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][1];
```

can be illustrated as

```
0x0001 -> int[][] of size 3, elements = [0x0123, 0x0456, 0x0789]

[address]
0x0123 -> int[] of size 1, elements = [0]
0x0456 -> int[] of size 1, elements = [0]
0x0789 -> int[] of size 1, elements = [0]

matrix = 0x0001
```

where `0x0001`, `0x0123`, `0x0456`, and `0x0789` are examples of reference values (think of it as an address to an object).

This

```
int[] vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

adds a new `int[]`

```
0x9999 -> int[] of size 7, elements = [1,2,3,4,5]

vector = 0x9999
```

and

```
matrix[0] = vector;
```

makes it

```
0x0001 -> int[][] of size 3, elements = [0x9999, 0x0456, 0x0789]
```

Comment: _where that element is initialized with the value 0_.. But local variables will not be assigned default values.. Is it different for arrays??

Comment: @Codebender This notation `new int[10]` creates an array of 10 `int` variables, all initialized to their default value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that in Java `int[][] matrix`, is not actually a matrix in the mathematical sense ... or in the sense of C, C++, FORTRAN and so on.

It is actually an array of arrays.  The type `int[][]` means "array of arrays of integers".  The arrays of integers don't need to be the same size.  They don't need to be distinct.  They can even be `null`.

In this case, you have created a data structure that looks like this:

```
matrix -> [ o , o , o ]
            |   |   |
            |   |   V
            |   |   [ 0 ]
            |   V
            |   [ 0 ]
            V
            [ 0 ]
```

The type is `int[][]` ... which in only constrains the "shape" of the array to be 2 dimensional

When you assign `vector`, you change the data structure to look like this:

```
matrix -> [ o , o , o ]
            |   |   |
            |   |   V
            |   |   [ 0 ]
            |   V
            |   [ 0 ]
            V
vector ---> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

This makes sense from the Java typing perspective.

---

> Why does Java accept this?

Because it makes sense ... according to the Java model of arrays, and array typing.

- It doesn't make sense if you try to equate Java arrays with mathematical matrices.  But they aren't the same thing.
- It doesn't make sense if you think that `matrix[0] = ...` is copying array elements.  But it isn't.  It is assigning a single reference.